# scrapy - download with correct extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have a following spider:

```
class Downloader(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sor_spider"
    download_folder = FOLDER

    def get_links(self):
        df = pd.read_excel(LIST)
        return df["Value"].loc

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = self.get_links()
        for url in urls.iteritems():
            index = {"index" : url[0]}
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url[1], callback=self.download_file, errback=self.errback_httpbin, meta=index, dont_filter=True)

    def download_file(self, response):
        url = response.url
        index = response.meta["index"]
        content_type = response.headers['Content-Type']

        download_path = os.path.join(self.download_folder, r"{}".format(str(index)))

        with open(download_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        yield LinkCheckerItem(index=response.meta["index"], url=url, code="downloaded")


    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        yield LinkCheckerItem(index=failure.request.meta["index"], url=failure.request.url, code="error")
```

It should:

1. read excel with links (`LIST`)
2. go to each link and download file to the `FOLDER`
3. log results in `LinkCheckerItem`(I am exporting it to csv)

That would normally work fine but my list contains files of different types - zip, pdf, doc etc.

These are the examples of links in my `LIST`:

```
https://disclosure.1prime.ru/Portal/GetDocument.aspx?emId=7805019624&docId=2c5fb68702294531afd03041e877ca84
http://www.e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=1173293
http://www.e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=1263289
https://disclosure.1prime.ru/Portal/GetDocument.aspx?emId=7805019624&docId=eb9f06d2b837401eba9c66c8bf5be813
http://e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=952317
http://e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=1042224
https://www.e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=1160005
https://www.e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=925955
https://www.e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=1166563
http://npoimpuls.ru/templates/npoimpuls/material/documents/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%2030.06.2016.pdf
http://нпоимпульс.рф/assets/download/sal30.09.2017.pdf
http://www.e-disclosure.ru/portal/FileLoad.ashx?Fileid=1166287
```

I would like it to save file with its original extension, whatever it is... Just like my browser when it opens an alert to save file.

I tried to use `response.headers["Content-type"]` to find out the type but in this case it's always `application/octet-stream` .

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse `Content-Disposition` header for the correct file name.